# Blogosphere: what is it?

Tags: meaning, nouns, computing, internet, technology

[Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blogosphere) :

> all the blogs (= records of personal thoughts and opinions) on the
> internet, and the people who write or read them

[Cambridge Business English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blogosphere) :

> all the opinions, articles, etc. that are published by people on internet blogs

The first definition includes the writers and readers, while the second excludes them, focusing only on the texts published.

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blogosphere) :

> all of the blogs or bloggers on the Internet regarded collectively

This one means the blogosphere can be the websites themselves, or the writers of the websites. I interpret as an XOR (Exclusive OR), meaning it cannot be both at the same time.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blogosphere) :

> The blogosphere is made up of all blogs and their interconnections. The term implies that blogs exist together as a connected community (or as a collection of connected communities) or as a social networking service in which everyday authors can publish their opinions.

Wikipedia has a more romantic view, telling the blogosphere is more than the sum of the parts, that is, summing all texts in all websites is not the blogosphere, because the website have interlinks, and the writers of the websites have social bonds too.

Probably more definitions could be bring up here, if I kept searching, but I believe I already made my point clear that I'm confused.

What is the most accurate definition of blogosphere out there (not limited to my examples)?

Comment: “This one means the blogosphere can be the websites themselves, or the writers of the websites. I interpret as an XOR (Exclusive OR), meaning it cannot be both at the same time.” Not an exclusive OR.

Comment: It's a fuzzy concept. What is the art world, or academia, or the music industry. You know some things are central and some are fringe or debatable.

Comment: If two dictionaries matched, why would we need two? The content of the blogosphere must be its core, with the writers on the edge, and their parents further away.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are overthinking the idea. The definitions you give, taken together, should give you a good idea of the concept of "the blogosphere".

If they don't the OED may be of help to you as it clearly shows the use of "-sphere", a suffix that indicates 'encompassing something' or "the whole of something":

> **blogosphere, n.**
>
> **Etymology:** < blog n. + -o- connective + -sphere comb. form, after biosphere n., ecosphere n. etc.
>
> **The cultural or intellectual environment in which blogs are written and read; blogs, their writers, and readers collectively, esp. considered as a distinct online network. Frequently with *the*.**
>
> *Brad Graham is said to have first used the word in a blog dated 10 September 1999 *(‘Goodbye, cyberspace! Hello, blogiverse! Blogosphere? Blogmos?’)*, but the Internet Archive Wayback Machine page captures of the blog taken between January 2000 and April 2002 do not contain the relevant paragraph.*

> 2002   W. Quick DailyPundit 5 Jan. (blog, Internet Archive Wayback Machine 21 Apr. 2002) in [www.iw3p.com](http://www.iw3p.com)   *I propose a name for the intellectual cyberspace we bloggers occupy: the Blogosphere.*